# Call specific constructor

Tags: java

In my class i have two constructor

```
public class Acc implements Serializable {
    ....
        public Acc() {
            super();
            ....
        }   
        public Acc(final Pays paysDefaut) {
            this();
            if (paysDefaut != null) {
                ...
            }
        }   
    ....
    }
```

My question is when i do

```
this.accAd = new ArrayList<Acc>(Voon.NB__MAX);
```

I want to call this constructor `public Acc(final Pays paysDefaut)` . It's possible ...?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried? What is your confusion about constructors?

Comment: i try this but it's not work `this.accAD = new ArrayList<Acc(paysDefaut)>(Voon.NB_MAX);`

Comment: You seem to be confusing generic type parameters with object instances..

Comment: What is `accAd`? You're just specifying the type in the `<>` not sending it an instance of that type.

Comment: I'll give a hint: `new ArrayList(int size)`, call that specific constructor for the `ArrayList` class. Now, does that answer how to call a specific constructor for your class?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it's my question

Comment: Calling the constructor of `ArrayList` doesn't call any constructor of `Acc`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils `private List<Acc> accAd; `

Comment: Best to read some [constructor documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/145/object-class-methods-constructor/14442/object-constructor#t=201608202244312595088).

Comment: You seem to think constructing a List<Acc> fills the list with Acc objects. It doesn't. You end up with an empty list, and must add elements to it, that you can construct the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do it the way you showed in your comment. You can use whatever constructor you like to add elements to the list but not inside the type declaration of a generic.

Simply do `this.accAd = new ArrayList<Acc>();`

and then

`this.accAd.add(new Acc(paysDefaut));`

Of course, since you declared your list as `List<Acc>`, the type can be inferred using the diamond operator (`<>`) in Java 7+.